# Как сделать чтобы при выполнении команды, случайное число каждый раз менялось?

Tags: python, aiogram

Вот у меня есть код:

```
import config
import logging
import random
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from filters import IsAdminFilter

rnd = random.randint(1, 2)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s',
                handlers=[logging.FileHandler("my_log.log", mode='w'),
                          logging.StreamHandler()])
stream_handler = [h for h in logging.root.handlers if isinstance(h, logging.StreamHandler)][0]
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

dp.filters_factory.bind(IsAdminFilter)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['usebebra'], commands_prefix='!/')
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
     await message.reply(' Ты занюхал бебру и кайфуешь.... ммммм')

if rnd == 1:
@dp.message_handler(commands=['zakladka'], commands_prefix='!/')
async def cmd(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply(' Ты успешно сделал закладку!')

if rnd == 2:

@dp.message_handler(commands=['zakladka'], commands_prefix='!/')
async def cmd(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
      await message.reply(' Тебя за жопу поймали менты!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
     executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если случаное число = 1, то выдает один результат
Если случайное число = 2, то другой
Но проблема в том, что после запуска число генерируется один раз, после чего оно сохраняете до перезапуска в переменной rnd.
Как мне сделать так чтобы оно генерировалось каждый раз заново при вызове команды?
Надеюсь объяснил понятно. Всем спасибо заранее!

Comment: Не хочу показаться моралистом, но вы тему для игры выбрали так себе. По сабжу поставьте генератор сч и условие в функцию.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['try'], commands_prefix='!/')
async def cmd(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1
            await message.reply(' You win!')
        else:
            await message.reply('‍♂️ You lose!')
```